# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRequired' of undefined (material ui )

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to switch from `@material-ui/core@3.9.3` to the latest current version of material `v4.4.3`, but I've got this error

[image]

It isn't clear for me in which snippet of code is this issue happens and how to fix it. Maybe someone has some ideas about it? Also, you can check all my dependencies in package.json file. Pls, let me know which info you need if it isn't clear and I will attach it.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.1.5",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "0.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.6",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.27",
    "enzyme": "3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.14.0",
    "history": "4.6.3",
    "humps": "2.0.0",
    "jss": "^10.0.0",
    "jss-camel-case": "6.1.0",
    "jss-default-unit": "8.0.2",
    "jss-expand": "5.3.0",
    "jss-extend": "6.2.0",
    "jss-global": "3.0.0",
    "jss-nested": "6.0.1",
    "jss-props-sort": "6.0.0",
    "jss-vendor-prefixer": "8.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.14",
    "moment": "2.23.0",
    "normalizr": "3.3.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "qs": "6.5.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-dropzone": "10.1.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.8.8",
    "react-image": "2.1.1",
    "react-intl": "2.7.2",
    "react-intl-po": "2.2.2",
    "react-intl-redux": "2.0.2",
    "react-jss": "^10.0.0",
    "react-motion": "0.5.2",
    "react-pose": "4.0.8",
    "react-redux": "7.0.3",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-spinners": "0.4.7",
    "react-universal-component": "4.0.0",
    "recompose": "0.30.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-form": "8.2.2",
    "redux-form-validators": "^3.2.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "store2": "2.7.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: Refer to [this](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/) link for migration.

Comment: I've done all steps from this tutorial, but I don't see any changes, see the same error, which steps in this tutorial can affect my issue?

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same issue. Updating prop-types package worked for me. I was on version `prop-types@15.6.0` but material v4 states `prop-types@^15.7.2` as a dependency. So try clean installing prop-types in your application. This worked for me.

```
  npm uninstall prop-types;
  npm install --save-exact prop-types@15.7.2;
```

How I figured it out: 
Had you clicked on SelectInput.js:361 it would have taken you to this line

[image: check namespaced variable prop_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default]

Which resolves to prop-types package.

[image: Check import]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import {PropTypes} from "prop-types";
```

Comment: It isn't clear where should I do it !? Issue happens outside of my code , In some material ui component , how can I fix it ?

Comment: Please explain why. according to prop types docs, the import should be import PropTypes from 'prop-types' https://github.com/facebook/prop-types